# How to get Text.XML.Cursor location?

Tags: xml, haskell

How can I `show` given Cursor's path in human friendly form (e.g. `root.element.childA`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ancestor`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml-conduit-0.7.0.1/docs/Text-XML-Cursor.html#v%3aancestor) is an [`Axis`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml-conduit-0.7.0.1/docs/Text-XML-Cursor.html#t%3aAxis) that gives you a list of all ancestors for the current cursor.
Using the [`node`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml-conduit-0.7.0.1/docs/Text-XML-Cursor-Generic.html#v%3anode) accessor of cursor, we can get back a [`Node`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml-conduit-0.7.0.1/docs/Text-XML.html#t%3aNode) and pattern match on the  [`NodeElement`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml-conduit-0.7.0.1/docs/Text-XML.html#v%3aNodeElement) constructor, converting down to a string with `show`, and packaging it all up in a convenient dot notation with `intersperse`.

```
import Data.List (intersperse)
import Text.XML (Node(elementName))
import Text.XML.Cursor (Cursor(node), ancestor)

prettyCursor :: Cursor node -> String
prettyCursor = intersperse "." . filter (not.null) . map (elemname.node) . ancestor
  where
    elemname (NodeElement Element{ elementName = e }) = show e
    elemname _ = ""
```

Comment: Can you extend your answer with comment about `Text.XML.Cursor.Generic`? Your answer is correct but my original problem involved trying to deconstruct `Text.XML.Cursor`.

Comment: Sorry to take so long to get back to you. The reason for `Text.XML.Cursor.Generic` is that most of what is in `Text.XML.Cursor` is simply re-exported from this package, and hence `Text.XML.Cursor.Generic` is where I was looking when tracking down types and functions that would work. Changing the name of the import to `Text.XML.Cursor` is functionally identical and I have updated my answer.